# knockout data-bind inputmask prevents change event

Tags: knockout.js

I have a data-bind that looks like this

```
<td><input type="text" data-bind="inputmask: { value:PayRate}, event:{change: $root.payRateChanged}" /></td>
```

The change event does not fire.  If I use the same syntax, but replace `change` with `blur`, the blur event does fire, but I really need the change event rather than blur.

If I change `inputmask: {value:PayRate}` to simply `value:PayRate`, the change fires, but now I have lost my inputmask-ing.

How can I invoke inputmask and still get the change event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `value: PayRate` to your input markup as well

```
<td><input type="text" data-bind="value: PayRate, inputmask: {value:PayRate}, event:{change: $root.payRateChanged}" /></td>
```

Without that, the input isn't actually getting bound to any value, thus it has no way to trigger a change event.